# How to position a button in fluidRow column

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm trying to place a `selectInput` box beside an `actionButton` in a shiny app, using `fluidRow` & `column` arguments. However the button gets placed at the top of its `column`. 
Using `text-align:center` in the `div` places the button centre-top in the `column` view. I'd like the `actionButton` to be at the same height as the `selectBox` on its left.

I'm just beginning to get into some `CSS` because of `Shiny` but am at a loss here.
Thanks in advance :)

```
ui <- fluidPage(title = "Working Title",

sidebarPanel(width = 6,
# *Input() functions
fluidRow(column(6, selectInput("Input1", label = h3("Select Input 1"), choices = list( "A" = "A", "B" = "B"), selected = 1)),
        column(6, div(style = "background-color:yellow; text-align:center;", actionButton("goButtonSetInput1", "SetInput1")))
        )
   )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by adding another fluidRow, and setting the label =NULL

```
ui <- fluidPage(title = "Working Title",

                sidebarPanel(width = 6,
                             # *Input() functions
                             fluidRow(column(6,  h3("Select Input 1") )), 
                             fluidRow(column(6, selectInput("Input1", label = NULL, choices = list( "A" = "A", "B" = "B"), selected = 1)),
                                      column(6, div(style = "background-color:yellow; text-align:center;", actionButton("goButtonSetInput1", "SetInput1")))
                             )
                )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep the labels intact and instead add line breaks in the columns that contain the misaligned actionButton (or checkboxInput etc). If the page is compressed then the labels will still be displayed immediately above the selectInput (or textInput etc), while the separate fluidrow solution by Eduardo will display all the labels and then all the inputs. the br() line breaks can be enclosed in the appropriate html tag function to get the right spacing, in this case h3(br()):

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Working Title",
  sidebarPanel(
    width = 6,
    # *Input() functions
    fluidRow(column(6, selectInput("Input1", label = h3("Select Input 1"), choices = list( "A" = "A", "B" = "B"), selected = 1)),
             column(6, h3(br()), div(style = "background-color:yellow; text-align:center;", actionButton("goButtonSetInput1", "SetInput1")))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```